# Saving data in conversation exits

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a google actions app and I am trying to save a variable between conversations. However if the cancel intent is invoked (the user says quit, exit, cancel etc. invoking actions_intent_CANCEL event) this data does not persist to the next conversation. I also have a custom save intent which too exits the conversation but it works fine.

This does not work (intent with event actions_intent_CANCEL)

```
app.intent('Exit', (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.verification === 'VERIFIED') {
    conv.user.storage.avar = 'somevalue';
  }
  conv.close('Goodbye!');
});
```

but this works (custom intent with no event)

```
app.intent('Save', (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.verification === 'VERIFIED') {
    conv.user.storage.avar = 'somevalue';
  }
  conv.close('Goodbye!');
});
```

In both cases the conversation exits and in the response there is the correct value for the variable.

```
"userStorage": "{\"data\":{\"avar\":\"somevalue\"}}"
```

However when I activate my app again, if exited via the Exit intent the data is missing or wrong. Does anyone know if this is bug or am I doing something wrong?

Help is appreciated!